# How to disable click active style (clickable DIV) on touch devices?

Tags: html, css

How to disable this blue background active effect (see GIF below).

[image]

This is not a link.

This is a DIV with an `onClick()` event handler attached to it.

**NOTE:** This is only occurring **on touch devices**. The mouse click does not trigger that effect.

This seems related to the `cursor:pointer;` property, which is set on the div.

When I remove it, the effect goes away. But I need the `cursor:pointer;` property.

Whant can I do to get rid of that effect?

Comment: What about Event​.prevent​Default()? In your onClick() method. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault

Comment: Just tried that. Didn't work.

Comment: Did you bind it like, `this.myObj.addEventListener('touchstart', evt=> this.myDiv_touchStart(evt), false);` and `e.preventDefault();` in your `myDiv_touchStart method?` I did something similar, worked for me.

Comment: I'm using React with React Hooks. The `-webkit-tap-highlight-color` did the trick for me. But thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this:

```
.your-class {
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}
```

Comment: I'm glad that I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

---

Try this

```
:focus {
        background-color: #ffffff;
    }
```

Comment: Add this css to the btn class. This css fixed the issue for me.

Comment: Maybe it would be better, if the background-color would be transparent, instead of white

Answer (score 0):

Try using css styling `outline: none;` For more info check: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/outline/